# I have a button that switches the theme of my website how do i make the same button if clicked again to change back to the default Theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

When the theme changer button is clicked it changes the colors of my website how do i make it so when the user clicks the button again it changes back to the original colors.

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ChangeTheme').click(function () {
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color1", "orange")
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color2", "red")
        document.body.style.setProperty("--color3", "white")
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS code:

```
:root {
    --color1: #3366cc;
    --color2: #2d2d2d;
    --color3: white;
}

#header {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0099ff;
    border-top: 5px solid #2d2d2d;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color2), var(--color1));
}

#footer {
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0099ff;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color1), var(--color2));
}
```

HTML code:

```
      <asp:Button ID="ChangeTheme" runat="server" Text="Change Theme" Width="110px" CausesValidation="false" BackColor="#99CCFF" BorderColor="#000066" BorderStyle="Solid" />
```

Comment: Use CSS class names instead of editting the style property. Then you can switch back and forth between adding and removing those class names. Else you would have to unset/reset all the styles seperately.

Comment: I don't know how to do that i am new to asp.net.

Comment: Welcome to web dev and SO then. :) I would advice you to read any CSS tutorial, since it's one of the early lessons. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors will take you a long way already. And since you use JQuery, you can use $( element ).toggleClass( className ) or good ol' element.classList.toggle() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an if statement, and check what is the `--color1` value, for example:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('#ChangeTheme').click(
        function(){
          if($("body").css("--color1")!=="orange"){
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color1", "orange");
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color2", "red");
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color3", "white");
          } else {
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color1", "#3366cc");
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color2", "#2d2d2d");
            document.body.style.setProperty("--color3", "white");
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: That dosent work it instantly changes back to the original colours.

Comment: Didn't work because i was using asp button instead of html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

document.body.classList.toggle('nameOfClass') //to toggle

document.body.classList.add('nameOfClass') //to add

document.body.classList.remove('nameOfClass') // to remove

Comment: What do you mean by the nameOfClass.

Comment: sorry for the delay
in the css instead of using id selectors, you can use class selectors
for example
.header {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0099ff;
    border-top: 5px solid #2d2d2d;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color2), var(--color1));
}
Then you can add or remove the class "header" to an element, or to the body
document.body.classList.toggle('header ');

Comment: ah ok thansk for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just css and js,
keep all your classes with the default color, with or without variables, and create a named class that you can apply to the specific elements.

```
:root {
    --color1: #3366cc;
    --color2: #2d2d2d;
    --color3: white;
}

#header {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0099ff;
    border-top: 5px solid #2d2d2d;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color2), var(--color1));
}

#footer {
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0099ff;
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color1), var(--color2));
}

#header.theme2 {
    background: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}
#footer.theme2 {
    background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
}
```

Your js code can look like this then:

```
function toggleTheme2(){
    ['#header', '#footer'].forEach(x=>document.querySelectorAll(x).forEach(x=>x.classList.toggle('theme2')))
}
```

and the html button:

```
<asp:Button ID="ChangeTheme" runat="server" onclick="toggleTheme2" Text="Change Theme" Width="110px" CausesValidation="false" BackColor="#99CCFF" BorderColor="#000066" BorderStyle="Solid" />
```